# cocos2d-x Ver3.5でcsvファイルに書かれた日本語文字を読み込み、テキストとして描画すると文字化けします。

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, c++11

こんにちは。ここを初めて利用するココスゴゴスです。
早速質問ですが、cocos2d-x Ver3.5でcsvファイル内の日本語文字列を読み込み、それをテキストやメニューとして描画すると文字化けしてしまいます。

開発環境は以下の通り。
eclipse、言語はC++、デバッグはandroid実機、実機のosはandroid4.0、cocos2d-xのバージョンは3.5です。

文字化けの詳しい流れは、以下のようなcsvファイルを読み込み、

数値,　日本語,　　　English,
1,　　　こんにちは,　Hello,

この『1,こんにちは,Hello』をまとめて一つの文字列とし、std::stringとして読み込んだ後、
それを以下のように扱い

```
LabelTTF::create(ここに読み込んだstd::string, "fonts/ume-pgo5.ttf", 48);
auto labelItem1 = MenuItemLabel::create(labelBtnLabel, CC_CALLBACK_1(Helloworld::myCallback, this));

auto menu = Menu::create(labelItem1,NULL);
menu->setPosition(Vec2(640/2 + 500,360/2));
this->addChild(menu);
```

メニューとして表示したのですが、日本語だけが文字化けして表示されます。
libcocos2dxのプロパティーのテキストファイルのエンコードをutf-8に変え、
フォントも日本語フォントである以下のものをダウンロードし、それに差し替えましたが、
http://osdn.jp/projects/ume-font/wiki/FrontPage

日本語だけがどうあがいても文字化けしてしまいます。
cocos2d-xを使い初めて、一週間です。
この原因が特定できず、ひどく悩んでいます。
アドバイスお願いします。

Comment: csvファイルのエンコーディングはUTF-8になっていますか？

Comment: なっていませんでした……
今修正したところ、日本語がちゃんと描画されました。
h2so5さん、回答ありがとうございます。
本当に助かりました。